# Statistical test for amplicon sequencing data

Tags: r, statistics

I have identified the top 50 genera based on the relative abundance in 16S amplicon sequencing data. Now I want to perform a statistical test to compare the two conditions; salt and non-salt. But not sure how to do a normality check and then how to do statistical tests for these multiple genera in R. One more issue in this data; there are lots of zeros.

```
data = read.table("statisticalTest.salt_vs_non_salt.txt",header=T,sep='\t',check.names=F)
head(data)

                          salt        salt        salt    non_salt    non_salt
1     Burkholderia 0.097731239 0.244541624 0.001426243 0.116990216 0.013678457
2   Bradyrhizobium 0.193819936 0.135586384 0.094290501 0.048097711 0.020956642
3 Anaeromyxobacter 0.103890771 0.087270334 0.139477497 0.117391401 0.219336751
4        Geobacter 0.008452247 0.018362646 0.016118808 0.045958054 0.051796890
5   Microbacterium 0.000513294 0.003237345 0.019378792 0.000156017 0.000538076
6    Methylocystis 0.008794443 0.010794689 0.004957892 0.001760760 0.002265583
    non_salt
1 0.27859036 
2 0.09660323 
3 0.20067454 
4 0.03892350 
5 0.00000000 
6 0.01459201
```

Many thanks

Comment: Seems like you are asking not one question but how to perform the whole analysis. That is not how this works.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I my first query is how I can check the  multiple genera (independent variable) normality based on treatment; salt vs non-salt (independent variable). I can it easily do for one variable like; Shapiro.test(data$Geobacter) and if not normally distributed then non parametric test like; Wilcox.text(data$Geobacter ~data$treatment).